# Stepwise reducing the input dataframe in a loop

Tags: r

I need to do iteratively evaluate the variance of a dataset while i reduce the data.frame row by row in each step. As an example

```
data <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
perc <- list("vector")
sums <- sum(data)

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {      
  data <- data[-1,]
  perc[[i]] <- sum(data)/sums # in reality, here are ~8 additonal lines of code
}
```

I dont like that `data` is re-initialized in every step, and that the loop breaks with an error, when `data` is emptied.
So the questions are:
1. How to express `data <- data[-1,]` in an incrementing way (something like `tmp <- data[-c(1:i),]`, which doesnt work?
2. Is there a way to stop the loop, before the last row is removed from data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
set.seed(123)
data <- matrix(runif(100),10,10)
sums <- sum(data)
perc <- lapply(2:nrow(data),function(x) sum(data[x:nrow(data),]/sums))
```

The above code yields the same result as your original code, but without error message and without modifying `data`.

```
perc1 <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {      
  data <- data[-1,]
  perc1[[i]] <- sum(data)/sums 
}
identical(perc,perc1)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you wish to preserve the `for` loop in order to perform other calculations within the loop, you could try:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {
  perc[[i-1]] <- sum(data[i:nrow(data),])/sums
  # do more stuff here
}
identical(perc,perc1)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you are using the loop index `i` for other calculations within the loop, you will most probably need to replace it with `i-1`. It may depend on what is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lapply

```
res <- lapply(2:nrow(data), function(i)sum(data[i:nrow(data),])/sums)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the loop part like this:

```
for (i in 2:nrow(data)) {      
  perc[[i - 1]] <- sum(data[i:nrow(data),])/sums # in reality, here are ~8 additonal lines of code
}
```